# Use ArcPy or Calculate Field to create a range of numbers 1:130 and repeat each number 129 times

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator

I need to perform a task that is quite simple, however I am having trouble getting my result into a feature class' attribute table. I have a feature class with 27,606 rows and an empty column that needs these repeating values sorted in order from 1 to 129. I am able to create a list and then a list of strings in the Python environment in ArcGIS Pro using the below code:

```py
import itertools

codeblk1=list(itertools.chain(*([x] * 129 for x in range(1,130))))
codeblk2=(",".join(map(str,codeblk1)))
print(codeblk2)
```

This results in the number 1 being repeated 129 times, then the number 2 being repeated 129 times, etc up to the number 129 being repeated 129 times. For example:
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, etc.

I am unable to insert or calculate my field to take on these repeated values. I am open to staying in the python environment and using ArcPy or sticking to the Calculate Field tool and using a function.

Here is a failed attempt in Calculate Field to use a function called plots() to populate my field "NEW" in my feature class with these repeated values.

```py
NEW = plots()
import itertools

def plots():
 codeblk1=list(itertools.chain(*([x] * 129 for x in range(1,130))))
 plots=(",".join(map(str,codeblk1)))
 return str(plots)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't attempt to use the values you've created.  There are plenty of examples of using a global variable to increment return function content, but you don't even have a function.

Comment: Yes I did not post my failed attempts at creating a function that implements the output of this code as I did not think it would be helpful and I have tried numerous iterations.

Comment: We can't help you fix what you haven't posted.

Comment: I updated the post accordingly

Comment: You should always follow the pattern in the documentation. The function should always return ONE value. You just need a global counter and function that returns "1" 127 times, then "2" 127 times,... You could use the list if you offset into it, but that's not the most efficient  methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A python solution using an [UpdateCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) could be this:

```py
import itertools
import arcpy

aL = list(itertools.chain(*([x] * 129 for x in range(1,130))))
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(myLayer,"NEW") as cursor:
   for i, row in enumerate(cursor, 0):
       row[0] = aL[i]
       cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This solution assumes the row of rows matches the number of items in the list.

Comment: Divmod(oid,129)[0] does the same in field calculator

Comment: @FelixIP, a very slick 1-liner solution, but I would add to it +1 so it would be `Divmod(oid,129)[0] + 1`, so it returns 1 to 129 instead of 0 to 128.

Comment: @Hornbydd...This worked thank you so much! I did make the mistake of NOT matching the number of rows to the number of items in my list. I should have used the range (1,215) to fill the 27,606 rows in my attribute table. Here is the code that worked for me in ArcPy:
"""import itertools
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

aL = list(itertools.chain(*([x] * 129 for x in range(1,215))))
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mylayer,"NEW") as cursor:   
       for i, row in enumerate(cursor, 0):       
       row[0] = aL[i]       
       cursor.updateRow(row)"""